# Show that the function $y = e^{2x}(A \cos3x + B \sin3x)$ satisfies the differential equation $y'' - 4y' + 13y = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Show that the function $y = e^{2x}(A \cos3x + B \sin3x)$ satisfies the differential equation $y'' - 4y' + 13y = 0$

**My attempt:**

I get
$y' = e^{2x}((2A + 3B) \cos3x + (2B - 3A) \sin3x)$.
$y'' = e^{2x} ((-5A + 12B) \cos3x + (-12A - 5B) \sin3x)$.
$y'' - 4y' + 13y = e^{2x} ((16A + 24B) \cos3x + (16B - 24A) \sin3x) = 0$.
$(16A + 24B) \cos3x + (16B - 24A) \sin3x = 0$.
$(2A + 3B) \cos3x + (2B - 3A) \sin3x = 0$

And I'm totally lost after this. It seems like this can't be true since I get
$\tan x = const$.

I'd appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: To avoid making mistakes verify separately that $e^{2x} \cos (3x)$ and  $e^{2x} \sin (3x)$ are both solutions of the given DE. Since any linear combination of solutions is a solution that would complete the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivatives $y'$ and $y''$ are correct, you've just made a mistake summing the whole thing.

$\begin{cases}
y'' & -5A+12B & -12A-5B\\
-4y' & -8A-12B & 12A-8B\\
13y & 13A+0B & 0A+13B\\\\
y''-4y'+13y & 0A+0B & 0A+0B
\end{cases}$

Comment: Yes, apparently I did $+4y'$ instead of $-4y'$. Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, $y''-4y'+13y$ is a linear ODE with characteristic equation $r^2-4r+13=0$ whose solutions are $r=2\pm 3i$ so $y=C_1e^{(2+3i)x}+C_2e^{(2-3i)x}$ or equivalently in real domain $e^{2x}(A\cos(3x)+B\sin(3x))$

Comment: thanks, it's currently very hard for me to understand what you wrote as I'm learning calculus on my own and I'm currently in the chapter about derivates, so I'll learn about differential equations much later

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}y' &= e^{2x}(-3A\sin 3x+ 3B\cos 3x) + 2e^{2x}(A\cos 3x + B\sin 3x) \\&= 3e^{2x}(-A\sin 3x+B\cos 3x)+2y\end{align}$

$\begin{align}y''&=3e^{2x}(-3A\cos 3x - 3B\sin 3x) + 6e^{2x}(-A\sin 3x+B\cos 3x)+2y'\\& = -9y + 6e^{2x}(-A\sin 3x + B\cos3x) + 6e^{2x}(-A\sin 3x+B\cos 3x) + 4y \\& = -5y +12e^{2x}(-A\sin 3x + B\cos 3x) \\&= -13y +12e^{2x}(-A\sin 3x + B\cos 3x)  + 8y \\& =-13y+ 4y'\end{align}$

So, $y'' - 4y' +13y = 0$